# Crossover parts of two std::array's

Tags: c++, arrays

I've these two std::array's:

```
std::array<int, 3> array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::array<int, 3> array2 = { 10, 20, 30 };
```

Now I want to crossover them at a defined index position (for example at 2) that the result is:

```
std::array<int, 3> array1 = { 10, 20, 3 };
std::array<int, 3> array2 = { 1, 2, 30 };
```

What is the best and easiest way to do that?

Comment: [`std::swap_ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges) - you would need to get iterators to the subrange you want to swap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a standard algorithm  [`std::swap_ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges) designed for this.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 3> array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::array<int, 3> array2 = { 10, 20, 30 };

    const int position = 2;
    std::swap_ranges(array1.begin(), array1.begin() + position, array2.begin());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the crossover rules you have, a trivial implementation is to have every second element:

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < array1.size();i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        std::swap(array1[i],array2[i])
}
```

Note: This assumes array1 and array2 have the same size.